# AngularJS doesn't enter controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm learning Angular with its [official tutorial](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.1/docs/tutorial/step_08) (step 8 at the moment). My problem is, when I have the list:

```
<ul class="phones">
    <li ng-repeat="phone in phones | filter: query | orderBy: orderProp">
        <a href="#/phones/{{phone.id}}"><span>{{phone.name}}</span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And I click on one of those elements, nothing happens (except from url being changed, but that seems normal, because it hash `#` before).

My js is:

`app.js`:

```
var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'phonecatControllers'
]);

phonecatApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/phones', {
                templateUrl: 'phone-list.html',
                controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'
            }).
            when('/phones/:phoneId', {
                templateUrl: 'phone-detail.html',
                controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl'
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/phones'
            });
    }]);
```

`controller.js`:

```
var phonecatControllers = angular.module('phonecatControllers', []);

phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
    function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('js/phones.json').success(function(data) {
            $scope.phones = data;
        });

        $scope.orderProp = 'name';
    }]);

phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http',
    function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
        alert($routeParams);
        $http.get('app/phones/' + $routeParams.phoneId + '.json').success(function(data) {
            console.log(data)
            $scope.phone = data;
        });
    }]);
```

What can I do? I even tried to copy the tutorial source for both js files, but this didn't help. Actually, nothing from `PhoneDetailCtrl` gets fired, neither `alert` nor `console.log`, not to mention `get`.

Comment: Any error in console ?

Comment: No, nothing. I also double-checked directories.

Comment: Shouldn't `$scope.phone = data;` be `$scope.phones = data;` ?

Comment: @OmriAharon - no, `phones` refers to multiple position on a list, `phone` is a single one used in `phone-detail.html`.

Comment: Did you declare `PhoneDetailCtrl` anywhere in the HTML ?

Comment: No, I copied `phone-detail.html` straight from the tutorial. `PhoneDetailCtrl` is the name of the controller.

Comment: I'm not aware of how a controller can be of service if you don't declare it in the HTML as `ng-controller="PhoneDetailCtrl"` and have it create a scope.

Comment: Cab you add `<ul class="phones" ng-controller="PhoneDetailCtrl">` and try ?

Comment: Obviously you need it to be declared under `ng-app="phonecatApp"` somewhere as well, as the controller's registered under that app.

Comment: It works! You're right, I thought that declaring controllers inside JS is sufficient. It turns out it isn't. Please post your answer and I'll be happy to accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the declaration of the controller(s) in the HTML, simply add whichever you need: (get function is under PhoneDetailCtrl/phones list is under PhoneListCtrl)

```
<ul class="phones" ng-controller="PhoneDetailCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="phone in phones | filter: query | orderBy: orderProp">
        <a href="#/phones/{{phone.id}}"><span>{{phone.name}}</span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Note that the element that you're declaring the controller on, in this case the `ul`, creates a scope where you can access the controller's scope variables and functions. So anywhere outside the `ul` will be "blind" to the `PhoneDetailCtrl` 
controller.

Comment: Do you mean `PhoneListCtrl`? In this case that is where `phones` is declared.

Comment: @Josh Yes, he will need both controllers. I added the answer subsequently to our comments' discussion where he tried to access a function in the `PhoneDetailCtrl`.